# regex variable lookbehind to match if not precedded by

Tags: regex

In this example:

```
no lorem lipsum rats
lorem rats lipsum no
rats lorem lipsum do
no mice lorem rats !
mice lorem lipsum do

# Match if contains 'rats' or 'mice' only if no preceded by 'no'.
```

I would like my regexp to match only if rats and mice are not precedded by no.

A naive solution would be to use a variable lookbehind which is not allowed with PCRE:

```
/(?<!no.*)(rats|mice)/
```

How can I make it works ?

Comment: Which platform do you use to run the regex?

Comment: PCRE supports lookbehind(which is your case), ain't it?

Comment: I use it on PCRE/php/Perl

Comment: @coin: PCRE doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds, but there's an alternative solution. See my answer below.

Comment: @coin what's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variable-length lookbehinds in PCRE. But you can emulate it using the magic sequence [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

```
^(?:(?!no).)*\K(rats|mice)
```

`(?:(?!no).)*` matches everything that is not followed by `no`, `\K` resets what has been matched so far, and `(rats|mice)` captures the word.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cA2tT8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use PCRE verbs, `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
(.*?no.*?(rats|mice).*)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:rats|mice)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/9)